# Sql server separate a string and pivot the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, pivot

I have a string that a get from a query, and separate by delimiter:

[image]

After that i need to put in columns instead of rows, this is what i'm doing from searching examples.

```
Declare @NomeAux varchar(255)
Declare @id int = 3059
select @NomeAux =  des_auxiliar from WKF_ProcessoItem  where Id_ProcessoItem = @id 

 SELECT   @id as id,Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') valores
 into #temp
FROM
(   
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@NomeAux, ';', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a);

SELECT 
    Id
,   [GSE]
,   [LOCAL]
,   [SN]
,   [Modelo]
,   [Fechadura]
,   [Vazio]
FROM #temp
PIVOT (
    max(valores)
    FOR valores IN ([GSE], [LOCAL], [SN],[Modelo],[Fechadura],[Vazio])
) AS PIVOTED
```

But I'm getting all values null like this:

I'm getting all values null

[image]

The result I need

[image]

Comment: I don't see what you need to split based on your results. Just pivot the table as is and see what you get.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a pretty strange way to store a EAV list (Entity-Attribute-Value), where the `id` marks the entity and the text is a *name-value-pair*. Try something along this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT,valores VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'[GSE] SAO')
,(1,'NOME DO LOCAL: CASH')
,(1,'SN:1111')
,(1,'MODELO: blah1')
,(1,'FECHADURA: 11')
,(2,'[GSE] SAO')
,(2,'NOME DO LOCAL: CREDIT')
,(2,'SN:2222')
,(2,'MODELO: blah2')
,(2,'FECHADURA: 22');

SELECT t.id
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN valoresXml.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')='[GSE] SAO' THEN t.valores END) AS GSE
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN valoresXml.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')='NOME DO LOCAL' THEN valoresXml.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') END) AS NomeDoLocal
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN valoresXml.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')='SN' THEN valoresXml.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') END) AS SN
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN valoresXml.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')='MODELO' THEN valoresXml.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') END) AS Modelo
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN valoresXml.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')='FECHADURA' THEN valoresXml.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') END) AS Fechadura

FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.valores,':','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(valoresXML)
GROUP BY t.id;
```

The result

```
id  GSE     NomeDoLocal SN      Modelo  Fechadura
1   [GSE] SAO    CASH   1111     blah1   11
2   [GSE] SAO    CREDIT 2222     blah2   22
```

The idea in short:

This technique is called "conditional aggregation" (kind of *old-fashioned* pivot).
We use XML to divide the text at the `:`-character (What about `[GSE] SAO`?).
We return a grouped set with the values taken conditionally.